# Reproduce Windows drag and drop with a custom image

Tags: windows, winapi, drag-and-drop

I am looking for a way to reproduce this behaviour from the Windows drag&drop file system :[image]

The cursor isn't visible with the default screencap feature of Windows, but of course it's on the right side file.
I'm looking to reproduce this right side image following the cursor in a program and setting the image myself. Having it be removed automatically on MOUSE_UP would be a big plus.
I'd like to use the Windows API directly so this process could work in the same way across languages, but if anyone has a better way I'm perfectly willing to hear it, of course.

Thanks.

Comment: see the DragWindow clipboard format https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/clipboard#dragwindow

Comment: Thanks, but I far as I'm aware this isn't what I asked for ; I want to reproduce the semi-transparent image (but giving Windows the image I want), not just define the cursor.